# Using Multiple Functions in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and using a function to load data using $http, that worked for me. After that I decided to do some form validation to see it's behaviour. I can do it individually but a bit confused on how can I merge my code with the above so that both of my functions work well.
The code is as:

```
    var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('any url or file')
    .then(function(result) {

      $scope.data = result.data;


    });
});
```

The controller is defined in the body attribute like this:

```
<body ng-controller="DataCtrl">
```

Now when I put the other function in the same app.js file, it doesn't work, can anybody help me out on this, the validation code is something like this:

```
    App.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

    if (isValid) {
      alert('submitting data');
    }
  };

});
```

The only thing I need to do this is to make them work like this:
1. Load data (working)
2. Implement validation with the help of second code block.

Comment: what do you mean by its not working? Is the function not getting invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to explain how the thing is working :)

When browser encounter this line `<body ng-controller="DataCtrl">` it will look for the defination of controller that is registered with the angular js. 
But in your case I guess you are registed controller two times like

**FIRST**

```
App.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('any url or file')
    .then(function(result) {

      $scope.data = result.data;


    });
});
```

**SECOND**

```
 App.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

    if (isValid) {
      alert('submitting data');
    }
  };

});
```

So one of the definition overwrites the other depending on the order of the registered method present in your script file.

So to overcome this you need to use only one registered controller:-

```
 App.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('any url or file').then(function(result) {

         $scope.data = result.data;


     });

      $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

          if (isValid) {
              alert('submitting data');
           }
      };
 });
```

Code credit :- S Vinesh

Comment: Actually you only have to use the third block. The first and second block are unnecessary. So you just have one controller. Hope you understand!.
Am I answering properly? Is this what u ask?

Comment: Hey @S Vinesh that's what I said to the OP he/she must have to use only one definition of controller instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

Just use it like below

```
 var App = angular.module('App', []);

 App.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('any url or file').then(function(result) {

         $scope.data = result.data;


     });

      $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

          if (isValid) {
              alert('submitting data');
           }
      };
 });
```